# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I am using a LINQ lambda expression like so:

```
int Value = 1;
qryContent objContentLine;

using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    objContentLine = (from q in db.qryContents
                      where q.LineID == Value
                      orderby q.RowID descending
                      select q).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Where is the error thrown?

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Can you give more details on the class `qryContent` and on the `db.qryContents` property?

Comment: Which line error is? This looks fine

Comment: Where, not which error. In the query? When evaluating it later? Because that code you posted can't produce the error, unless it is in `db.qryContents`.

Comment: the column i am using LineID is integer type. qryContent is a view in db.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058487/entity-framework-cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it?rq=1 maybe this will help?

Comment: it is in lambda expression. it is a build error.

Comment: oh yea thanks guys. actually namespace was missing.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

I think you are missing `using System.Linq;` from this system class.

and also add `using System.Data.Entity;` to the code

Comment: I actually had this issue just a few minutes prior and I had usings for System.Linq and System.Data.Entity.  I had to remove them, run a failed build and then readd them to the file.  Then it worked.

Answer (score 99):

In my case, I had to add `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: @Ryan Kohn I have applied all the solution methods described here, but none of them not solved my problem. So, could you have a look at please described on Kendo UI : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @H.Johnson Note that I only edited this answer. *skb* is the original author. On another note, if your problem is not identical to the one described in the question, you can consider asking a new question to the community.

Comment: @RyanKohn: Thanks for reply. Here is the link of my question. Could you have a look at pls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354301/convert-lambda-expression-to-json-in-mvc

Comment: I was missing `using System.Net; `  but this helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 21):

My case it solved i was using

```
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.TypeId ...)
```

using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeId ...)
```

will solve it

Answer (score 9):

If it's not related to missing using directives stated by other users, this will also happen if there is another problem with your query.

Take a look on VS compiler error list :
For example, if the "Value" variable in your query doesn't exist, you will have the "lambda to string" error, and a few errors after another one more related to the unknown/erroneous field.

In your case it could be :

```
objContentLine = (from q in db.qryContents
                  where q.LineID == Value
                  orderby q.RowID descending
                  select q).FirstOrDefault();
```

Errors:

> Error 241 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
>
> Error 242 Delegate 'System.Func<..>' does not take 1 arguments
>
> Error 243 The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context

Fix the "Value" variable error and the other errors will also disappear.

Answer (score 5):

For people just stumbling upon this now, I resolved an error of this type that was thrown with all the references and using statements placed properly. There's evidently some confusion with substituting in a function that returns DataTable instead of calling it on a declared DataTable. For example:

This worked for me:

```
DataTable dt = SomeObject.ReturnsDataTable();

List<string> ls = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr["name"].ToString()).ToList<string>();
```

But this didn't:

```
List<string> ls = SomeObject.ReturnsDataTable().AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr["name"].ToString()).ToList<string>();
```

I'm still not 100% sure why, but if anyone is frustrated by an error of this type, give this a try.

Comment: THANKS!  

Here's my iteration:

dtSQLServers.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr["SourceSystem"].ToString() == "xxxxxxxxx").ToList()