# Convert lambda expression to Json in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda, kendo-ui

I get an error ("Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type") during converting the lambda expression in controller. I have 3 entities in as below:

**Entities:**

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Course { get; set; }  

    public int CityID { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}


public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }    
}


public class Region
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var dataContext = repository.Students;
        var students = dataContext.ToDataSourceResult(request, m => new 
        {
            ID = m.ID,
            Course = m.Course,

            City = m.City.Name, //I can get City name and show it in View.
            MyRegionName = m.City.Region.Name //I can get region name and assign it to 
//"MyRegionName" parameter in JSON. However in View I cannot get it using "MyRegionName" paremeter  
        });           

        return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.ID);
        columns.Bound(m => m.Course);
        columns.Bound(m => m.City);
        columns.Bound(m => m.MyRegionName);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index_Read", "Student"))
    )        
)
```

Here is the point that may cause the problem in the Controller and View:

```
City = m.City.Name, //I can get City name and show it in View.
MyRegionName = m.City.Region.Name //I can get region name and assign it to the  "MyRegionName" parameter in JSON. However in View I cannot get it using "MyRegionName" paremeter.
```

May it be related to that there is `City` parameter in the Student entity. But there is no `MyRegionName` property in the `City` entity.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this happens because there is no property called `MyRegionName` for the `Student` class.

You have two options

1) Create a ViewModel that looks like your Student model but make it has such property. Also make sure inside the projection function of the `ToDataSourceResult` you create those new ViewModel types instead of anonymous object.

2) Just use a Template column. e.g.

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("MyRegionName").ClientTemplate("#=MyRegionName#");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I would like to use the 2nd option as it is really very simple. On the other hand, there is a little problem: The column header does not seem to be the other column headers. I tried to find the class the others and use on this header, but it did not work (using "k-link" class). Any idea that I can apply standard kendo ui grid header class to this one? I tried to use header attributes as below, but not worked. Many thanks again.

Comment: columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("MyRegionName").ClientTemplate("#=MyRegionName#").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-link" });