# Returning the value that was passed into a mocked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method on an interface:

`Someclass DoSomething(Someclass whatever);`

I can't do `.Returns(x => x)` because of the error:

> cannot convert lambda expression to type Someclass because it is not a
>   delegate type.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197481/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t)

Comment: use proper tag and don't include it question title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at these method overloads:

```
Returns(TResult value)
Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult> valueFunction)
```

It seems quite obvious for you that C# compiler should pick second overload. But actually C# compiler is unable to infer type of generic parameter `T` from argument `x => x` which you are passing. That's why compiler picks non-generic version of method and tries to convert lambda to SomeClass.

To fix this issue you should help compiler to infer type of generic parameter `T`. You can do it by explicitly specifying type of delegate argument:

```
.Returns((SomeClass x) => x);
```

Or you can specify type of `T` manually

```
.Returns<SomeClass>(x => x)
```

Comment: FYI this appears to not work for `mock.SetupSequence(...).Returns(...)` calls , only `mock.Setup(...).Returns(...)` calls

Answer (score 1):

You can create a instance of `someclass` and return the same like

```
someclass cl = new someclass
{
//property initialization
};

mockinstance.Setup(s => s.DoSomething(cl)).Returns(cl);
```