# LINQ query not working with Select2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using the Select2 plugin for searching on my table through LINQ. The issue I'm facing is the multi-select returns me an array and I get an error that I cant convert `string[]` to `string`. Here is my view:

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple"name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">Select a country...</option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>
```

I want on the controller to search records that I select from the dropdown. My controller is:

```
var model = from r in db.Clients
  orderby r.DateRegister descending
  where (r.DateRegister >= datepicker3 && r.DateRegister <= datepicker2 || datepicker2 == null || datepicker3 == null)
  where r.Name.Contains(FirstName) || FirstName == "" || FirstName == null
  where r.LastName.Contains(LastName) || LastName == "" || LastName == null
  where r.Phone.Contains(Phone) || Phone == "" || Phone == null
  where r.Email.Contains(Email) || Email == "" || Email == null
  where r.PromoCode.Contains(PromoCode) || PromoCode == "" || PromoCode == null
  where r.Brand.Contains(Brand) || Brand == "" || Brand == null
  where r.Rentetiion == Retetion || Retetion == null
  where r.SaleStatus == statos || statos == null
  where r.Desk == desk || desk == null
  where r.workerId == Broker || Broker == null
  where r.Country.Contains(country)||country == null
```

Where `country` will be more then 1 item to search.

Comment: Try this Eni, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Comment: so yuor `r.Country` have only one country save in your table right?

Comment: Yes r.Country got only 1 record.

Comment: Eni, if you to .ToList() for country, does that help?

Comment: @EniSpetsi, try this `where country.Any(c => c.Trim().ToLower().Contains(r.CountryName.Trim().ToLower()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Suppose this is your `Country` model.

```
class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

2) And this `string[]` contains country from your select2.

```
string[] country = new string[2] { "India", "Shrilanka" };
```

3) And those are the countries that are already in my database.

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
countries.Add(new Country { Name = "India", Code = "IN" });
countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Australia", Code = "AU" });
countries.Add(new Country { Name = "Shrilanka", Code = "SL" });
```

4) Then I used below query to filtered out countries from my database with above `string[]` that contains only 2 countries.

```
var query = (from r in countries
        where country == null || country.Any(c => c.Trim().ToLower().Contains(r.Name.Trim().ToLower()))
        select new
        {
           CountryName = r.Name,
           CountryCode = r.Code
        });


var result = query.ToList();
```

`Trim()` => Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current System.String.

`ToLower()` => Returns a copy of this string converted to lowercase.

**Output:**

[image]

Try once may it help you.

Comment: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.String[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context i get this erro now.

Comment: set your `country[]`  from select2 list is in `string[]` so this error will be gone

Comment: i got it like that.

Comment: @Eni Spetsi, View the updated answer carefully might be it help you :)

Comment: @EniSpetsi, add this condition in your where `country == null` that i added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
where r.Country.Contains(c => Country.Contains(c.country) || c.country == null)
```

Comment: i get this error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is

Comment: @Eni, try to import namespace `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: same error: S1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @EniSpetsi please make sure on ershoaib's comment.  It typically can be the fix.  Example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197481/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t