# Add Where clause to IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query:

```
public IQueryable GetOrder(int id)
{
  using (Context = new MyEntities())
  {
    IQueryable query = Context.Orders
     .Include("Customers")
     .Include("Products")
     .Include("OrderLines")
     .Where(o => o.OrderID == id);
    return query;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to extract the basic query (everything sans the `.Where` clause) so I can reuse it in other methods.  I tried this:

```
private IQueryable GetIncludes(MyEntities context)
{
  return context.Orders
   .Include("Customers")
   .Include("Products")
   .Include("OrderLines");
}

public IQueryable GetOldOrders()
{
  using (Context = new MyEntities())
  {
    DateTime ninetyDaysAgo = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90));

    IQueryable query = GetIncludes(Context);
    query = query.Where(o => o.OrderDate < ninetyDaysAgo);
    return query;
  }
}
```

but the compiler tells me it `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`.

I looked at [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197481/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t) and can report that I am using `System.Linq` (and `System.Linq.Dynamic`) and `System.Data.Entity`.  `System.Data.Entity` is greyed out in VS.

How do I create an `IQueryable` that I can add a `.Where` clause to after it's created?

Comment: You need an `IQueryable<Order>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a entity type into IQueryable

```
private IQueryable<Order> GetIncludes(MyEntities context)
{
  return context.Orders
   .Include("Customers")
   .Include("Products")
   .Include("OrderLines");
}
```

then update where you call this method

```
IQueryable<Order> query = GetIncludes(Context);
```