# is it possible to use projection to reduce the data overhead of this query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm returning a value from related tables into a computed column, and I am wondering if it can be optimized further.

Here is the code

```cs
File:EnergyOracleService.cs (Excerpt)
public partial class EnergyOracleService
partial void OnInvoicesRead(ref IQueryable<Models.EnergyOracle.Invoice> items);

public async Task<IQueryable<Models.EnergyOracle.Invoice>> GetInvoices(Query query = null)
{
   var items = Context.Invoices.AsQueryable();
   items = items.Include(i => i.Order1);
   items = items.Include(i => i.AccountEntry);
   items = items.Include(i => i.PaymentTerm);
   if (query != null)
      {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Expand))
         {
          var propertiesToExpand = query.Expand.Split(',');
          foreach(var p in propertiesToExpand)
            {
            items = items.Include(p.Trim());
            }
          }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.Filter))
          {
          if (query.FilterParameters != null)
             {
             items = items.Where(query.Filter, query.FilterParameters);
             }
          else
             {
             items = items.Where(query.Filter);
             }
          }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.OrderBy))
          {
          items = items.OrderBy(query.OrderBy);
          }
       if (query.Skip.HasValue)
          {
          items = items.Skip(query.Skip.Value);
          }
       if (query.Top.HasValue)
          {
          items = items.Take(query.Top.Value);
          }
    }
OnInvoicesRead(ref items);
return await Task.FromResult(items);
     }

File: EnergyOracleService.Custom.cs
public partial class EnergyOracleService
partial void OnOrderShippingsRead(ref IQueryable<OrderShipping> items)
{
    items = items.Include(i => i.OrderShippingDetails
        .Where(osd => osd.OrderDetail1.Order == osd.OrderShipping1.Order))
        .ThenInclude(OSD => OSD.OrderDetail1.Product1).AsSplitQuery();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        //var W = item.OrderShippingDetails.Sum(OSD => (decimal)OSD.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight * OSD.Quantity);
        var W = item.OrderShippingDetails.Sum(OSD => OSD.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight2 * OSD.Quantity);//*
        //var W = item.OrderShippingDetails.Select(osd => (decimal)osd.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight * osd.Quantity).Sum();
        //var W = item.OrderShippingDetails.Select(osd => new {osd.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight2} * new {osd.Quantity}).Sum();
        //var W = context.OrderShippingDetails.Where(osd => osd.OrderShipping == item.Id).Select(osd => (decimal)osd.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight * osd.Quantity).Sum();
        item.Weight = W ?? 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried using anonymous types but just got errors, is there any way I can just return the weight and quantity results or preferably their product? As EF returns many columns and much data that just isn't used, and it seems quite wasteful!
Previous iterations of the query have been commented out in no particular order. I have improved performance massively, but I'm wondering if there are further gains to be had
I'm a part time coder and not in any way fluent in either c# or Linq, hope you can help

The project is a Radzen Server-side Blazor
The file 'EnergyOracleService.cs' is auto generated so I'm stuck with that.
The file'EnergyOracleService.custom.cs' is where I can place extensions to existing partial methods to customise things, here I'm adding a computed value 'Weight' to the 'OrderShipping' table thus:

```cs
public partial class OrderShipping
{
[NotMapped]
public decimal Weight
   {
   get;
   set;
   }
}
```

Edited to add extra context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly:

I would get rid of the Include statement. I guess its not neccessary here, and by removing it we can avoid fetching unnecessary columns and data.

Secondly:

I would remove that foreach too. You make too many separate linq's in a loop. It's time consuming.

I prepared a pseudo code how your function could look like:

```
partial void OnOrderShippingsRead(ref IQueryable<OrderShipping> items)
{
    items = items.Select(os =>
    {
        Id = os.Id,
        Weight = os.OrderShippingDetails
            .Sum(osd => osd.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight2 * osd.Quantity) ?? 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I'm getting an error, do I need to 're-add' all the previous members of the items collection from the other half of the partial class
?

Comment: @Ian I dont really understand what other problem you have now. I would need to get a full context of that problem, and preferably in an edit of current question with info what you did, what happend, what is supposed to happen with minimal reproducible example so i could reproduce it in my PC.
You asked how to improve performance and i showed one of possible ways to achieve what you want, if that is giving you an error, i would need additional info.

Comment: I've edited the question to provide more context.

Comment: using your code I tried the following:

Comment: ```
items =  items.Select(os => new OrderShipping
   {
   Weight = os.OrderShippingDetails
      .Sum(osd => osd.OrderDetail1.Product1.Weight2.GetValueOrDefault()*osd.Quantity)
   });
```
which failed as it replaces the items object, I need add/edit the weight collection to/in it

Comment: @Ian Yes, there was a little mistake. It was caused by that we created a new object for every object in collection, instead we should work on your current collection. I just updated an answer, please check if it meet your needs, and accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, I'm getting an error at the closing braces saying "; Expected", I've tried placing a semicolon in various places and playing with the braces to no avail, is it something to do with the curly braces?

Comment: @Ian try now. I guess the semicolon is needed at the end of sum. I just corrected it, try now.

Comment: I've tried this, I get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" flagged on the lambda. Thanks again.

Comment: This is probably another issue, not related to my answer. It was already answered multiple times on stackoverflow. You can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197481/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'll accept your answer and research this error