# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I know these question(s) has been asked

1. [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197481/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t)
2. [Entity Framework - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058487/entity-framework-cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it)

But none of them has helped me to find the problem that i am facing

i have tried to use this solution

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.TextBox(model => model.Postcode_area_name, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
    </div>
</div>
```

to make one edit field read only, but i do get an error of 
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type
i do use entity frame work and these using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CRM2.Models;
```

the suggestion on other questions are that using

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
```

should fix the problem but it does not work for me 
I am using MVC 5

i have fixed the issue by using this solution

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name)
```

but because i am new on MVC and entity frame work i want learn why the other way throw an error

Sorry for English "mistake"
Thank you

Comment: You wrote `@Html.TextBox` instead of `@Html.TextBoxFor` note the `For`??

Comment: @ Callum Linington You are right For was my mistake But 1) when i use for it make the text box really ugly (I know i can use CSS to change the appearance of text box), 2) the update will not get the value of the text  box and change the value to null

Comment: @RezaDel So long as you are using `@Html.TextBoxFor` as Callum suggested, then the DefaultModelBinder should assign the value correctly in your POST.

Comment: Also, `@Html.TextBox` and `@Html.TextBoxFor` shouldn't render any differently in HTML. They will both have the `name` attribute to whatever you set as the first argument. Difference between the 2 is one lets you type a `name` manually, the other uses the lambda expression to set the `name`

Comment: @Geoff James i have tried the answer from Callum and it does get ride of an error but on the update the value is updated to NULL

Comment: @RezaDel, The reason your get it as `null` is because you have disabled it (disabled controls do not submit a value) - make it just `new { @readonly = "readonly" }`

Comment: Good spot @StephenMuecke! Hayfever getting the best of my reading abilities

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thank you very much you are right the disabled was the issue. @ Callum Linington if you add your comment as an answer i will accept it as a correct answer, Thank you all

Comment: @RezaDel I added my comment and stephens as answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your original code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.TextBox(model => model.Postcode_area_name, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
    </div>
</div>
```

You should change it to:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, the addition of `For` on the `TextBox` and the removal of `disabled = "disabled"`

The reason for removing `disabled` as per @StephenMuecke

> disabled controls do not submit a value

The reason for adding `For` is that it's extension method signature has the first parameter of an expression

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Postcode_area_name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

As you are using tightly bound entities

Comment: it does get ride of an error but i dont know why it does not update the filed with the data from the text box and it update it to NULL

Comment: can you share me your controller method