# MVC: DropdownListFor error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, lambda

I have the following problem.

I have a table which is called `Users` and I have another table called `Department`.

Now I want, that in the UI, when a user is going to create himself as user with the user form, that he get's on the department field a dropdown list  all Department titles which are available from Department table. Reason for that: Department table will be used for other operations and should not be linked with the Userdata. So the Userdata should only contain the department name from the table, and that is enough.

My Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult UserCreate()
{
    ViewBag.AppDataDepartment = new SelectList(database.department, "department_title", "department_title");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserCreate(Users user)
{
    if (user.UserID == "" || user.UserID == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "UserID cannot be blank");
    }
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<string> results = database.Database.SqlQuery<String>(string.Format("SELECT UserID FROM USERS WHERE UserID = '{0}'", user.UID)).ToList();
            bool _userExistsInTable = (results.Count > 0);
            Users _user = null;
            if (_userExistsInTable)
            {
                _user = database.Users.Where(p => p.UserID == user.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (_user != null)
                {
                   if(_user.active == true)
                    { 
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "USER already exists!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        database.Entry(_user).Entity.active = true;
                        database.Entry(_user).Entity.Last_Modified = System.DateTime.Now;
                        database.Entry(_user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        database.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _user = new Users();
                _user.UserID = user.UserID;
                _user.lastname = user.lastname;
                _user.firstname = user.firstname;
                _user.mail = user.mail;
                _user.department = user.department;
                _user.user_image = user.user_image;
                _user.image_path = user.image_path;
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                    _user.active = true;
                    _user.Last_Modified = System.DateTime.Now;
                    database.Users.Add(_user);
                    database.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.AppDataDepartment = new SelectList(database.department, "department_title", "department_title");
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //return base.ShowError(ex);
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

That is my HTML section:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "UserID", new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserID, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label form-control", @id = "inputEmail3" })
    </div>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department, "Department", new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList(model => model.department, (SelectList) ViewBag.AppDataDepartment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And Finally my department class from the table:

```
[Table("department")]
public partial class department
{
    [Key]
    public int departmentid { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string department_title { get; set; }
    public string subdepartment { get; set; }
}
```

But I can not compile, because I get the Error:

> Error CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because
>   it is not a delegate type BTKPI

Why does this not work? How can I fix that?

I have already looked at this [SolutionProposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058487/entity-framework-cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it), but this didn't helped, because the model, Linq and Data.Entity is already referenced.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor()` not `@Html.DropDownList()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, but then I get the following error message: 
Error CS1928 'HtmlHelper<Users>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, object)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You have so much bad code its a wonder anything works. What is the model you binding to? (all you have shown is `class department` but that does not contain a property named `department`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh ok, now it works, I have written the Select List again. I was trying something other, and therefor I have removed it.
But never the less, thank you very much. But for reason of getting better in coding (I'm really new in this topic), what is making my code bad? How could I improve it, to get good code?

Comment: Far too much to list it all. But I will give you a few links to study tomorrow.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, perfect, thanks very much. I would appreciate it, if you would not forget it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be `DropDownListFor()`, not `DropDownList()`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.department, (SelectList)ViewBag.AppDataDepartment, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If you were to use `DropDownList()`, then it would be

```
@Html.DropDownList("department", (SelectList)ViewBag.AppDataDepartment, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However there are numerous other issues with your code which you should address.

1. Your controller should be `UserController` and the method `Create()`
   so that the url will be `../User/Create`, not `User/UserCreate`
2. Your editing data, so you should be using a view model (do not use
   data models when editing data) - refer [What is ViewModel in
   MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc),
   and the view model should contain a property
   `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList` - a typical example is
   shown in [this
   question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o).
3. Your `Users` table should be storing the `ID` of the `Department`,
   not its name, and there should be a FK relationship to the
   `Departments` table.
4. Your view model property for `UserID` should have a `[Required]`
   attribute and the view should include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor(m
   => m.UserID)` so that you get bothe client and server side validation (ditto for the `DepartmentID` property). You should also
   consider a `RemoteAttribute` applied to the `UserID` property so
   that you get client side validation - refer [How to: Implement
   Remote Validation in ASP.NET
   MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx)

And finally, almost nothing is you POST method is making much sense. You calling the database twice in order to check if the user already exists. You checking `ModelState.IsValid` multiple times. Your `user_image` and `image_path` properties suggest you need to upload an image, but nowhere do you save it. You assign `ViewBag.AppDataDepartment` and then immediately redirect to the `Index()` method. Your code should look something like (ignoring the file upload issue)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserVM model)
{
    // Return early
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // You will enter this automatically of UserID is null
        model.DepartmentList = ... // assign the SelectList
        return View(model);
    }
    // One database call to check if the user exists
    User user = database.Users.Where(p => p.UserID == model.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user != null && !user.active)
    {
        user.active = true;
        // Save and redirect
    }
    else if (user != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "USER already exists!");
        model.DepartmentList = ... // assign the SelectList
        return View(model);
    }
    user = new User
    {
        UserID = model.UserID,
        lastname = model.lastname,
        .... // set other properties of User
        Last_Modified = System.DateTime.Now
    }
    // Save and redirect
}
```

Although its unclear why an existing user who has been archived would need to navigate to a `Create()` method (and be presented a form to fill out a whole lot of details they have already entered previously). You should have a separate method for activating previously archived users.

Comment: Actually This is the administrator User Control. I have implemented an RBAC Model, which has roles, permissions and users. They are all together in a Controller Admin. That's why I have the action name like CreateUser, because I have also CreateRole &  CreatePermission. The links you have postes are very helpful.

Comment: Then you should be using [Areas](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very logically. I will try to implement it today :) Thanks for the help and the links.