# C# Linq with MVC, Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, linq, controller

So I am really new to MVCs. I've been teaching myself for a project at work.

I am trying to print out my lists to my webpage from my SQL database for some inventory items and I keep getting this error:

*"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"*

I know there are some forms indicating adding some using statements, I still have the issue even after trying some of the solutions.

My controller looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LinqApplication.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace LinqApplication.Controllers
{
    public class InventoryItemController : Controller
    {
        // GET: InventoryItem
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IM_importEntities import = new IM_importEntities(); //our object to work with
            List<InventoryItem> items = import.inventory_items.Where(x => x.itemnum == "480-15").Select(x => new InventoryItem{itemnum =x.itemnum}).ToList(); //x commands

            items.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.itemnum)); //foreach loop for items
            
                return View(items.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

And my view looks like this:

```
@model List<LinqApplication.Models.InventoryItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName(model => model.itemnum)
        </th>  
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemnum)
        </td>
         
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And the error is underlined at:
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemnum)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try following some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058487/entity-framework-cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it

Comment: yes thats the one I've been using to try and solve the issue. I couldn't find anything that helped solve what I was looking for. I tried the "using" commands, I tried to change some of the statements, but it still comes back to this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `@Html.DisplayName(model => model.itemnum)` to `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].itemnum)`.
you need `DisplayNameFor` to use an expression, `DisplayName` just displays a string.

Comment: seems to be giving the error in the "itemnum" part now, verses the whole statement. maybe we're getting somewhere here.

Comment: I get: 

'List<InventoryItem>' does not contain a definition for 'itemnum' and no accessible extension method 'itemnum' accepting a first argument of type 'List<InventoryItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try `model => model[0].itemnum`

Comment: you are a legend. 
how did you know? why? i need answers LOL. thank you!

Comment: if this answers your question please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it